# Assign random values to an array of objects using a created class

Tags: java, arrays

**Situation (new in java):**

I would like to store random values into an array of objects of a class i created.
I created the following class:

```
private double color;
private double size;

// default constructor
public Example() {
    color = 0.0;
    size = 0.0;
}

// second constructor taking two arguments
public Example(double color, size imaginary){
    this.color=color;
    this.size=size;
}
// mutators
public void setColor(double c){
    color=c;
}
public void setSize(double s){
    size=s;
}
```

**Now in my driver class:**

I created the following

```
import java.lang.Math;

int num = 4;
Example[] array;
array = new Example[num];

for(int i=0;i<num-2;i++)
{
randomColor = Math.random();
randomSize = Math.random();
array[i].setColor(randomColor);
array[i].setSize(randomSie);
}
```

When i run the program i get the following error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Im assuming that the content in each element of the array is null. But why is that? and how do i make the logic above work ?

Obviously i want to stay within the boundaries of my knowledge which is around the complexity of this code.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only created an array of `Example` objects, but every element of it is `null` since you haven't created any `Example` object instances.

Arrays of "reference types" (anything that is a `class`, `interface`, `enum` or array, basically) start out with having `null` references in every element, and you still need to create the objects to put in the array.

Change your code to :

```
array[i] = new Example(randomColor, randomSize);
```

which will create new `Example` objects, and assign the random values to its properties.

Comment: that makes total sense. i didn't think of the new operator because i had put this before         array = new Example[num]; And I thought that initialized every object to 0.0 due to the default constructor